# C++ error: 'Dot' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, sdl

Please help with this error. I am using a compiler called Code::Blocks.
Here is my code.

```
#ifndef PROTOTYPES_H_INCLUDED
#define PROTOTYPES_H_INCLUDED

//The headers
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include "Dot.h"
#include "vars.h"

using namespace std;

bool load_files( Dot &thisDot, Uint32 &bg );

#endif // PROTOTYPES_H_INCLUDED
```

When I try declare a prototype with the Dot parameter inside a header I get this annoying error. s "Dot was declared in this scope". Can anybody help with these errors they are really hindering my progression >.<

Here is the actual function which is inside a different a .cpp file inside the same directory (don't worry about linking, thats taken care of by the compiler):

```
bool load_files( Dot &thisDot, Uint32 &bg ) {
    //Load the dot image
    dot = load_image( "spritesheet.png" );

    //Open font
    font = TTF_OpenFont( "lazy.ttf", 28 );

    //If there was a problem in loading the dot
    if( dot == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }

    if( font == NULL ) {
        return false;
    }

    //Open a file for reading
    std::ifstream load( "game_save" );

    //If the file loaded
    if( load != NULL )
    {
        //The offset
        int offset;

        //The level name
        std::string level;

        //Set the x offset
        load >> offset;
        thisDot.set_x( offset );

        //Set the y offset
        load >> offset;
        thisDot.set_y( offset );

        //If the x offset is invalid
        if( ( thisDot.get_x() < 0 ) || ( thisDot.get_x() > SCREEN_WIDTH - DOT_WIDTH ) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        //If the y offset is invalid
        if( ( thisDot.get_y() < 0 ) || ( thisDot.get_y() > SCREEN_HEIGHT - DOT_HEIGHT ) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        //Skip past the end of the line
        load.ignore();

        //Get the next line
        getline( load, level );
        load >> DOT_DIRECTION;

        //If an error occurred while trying to read the data
        if( load.fail() == true )
        {
            return false;
        }

        //If the level was white
        if( level == "White Level" )
        {
            //Set the background color
            bg = SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );
        }
        //If the level was red
        else if( level == "Red Level" )
        {
            //Set the background color
            bg = SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 );
        }
        //If the level was green
        else if( level == "Green Level" )
        {
            //Set the background color
            bg = SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00 );
        }
        //If the level was blue
        else if( level == "Blue Level" )
        {
            //Set the background color
            bg = SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF );
        }

        //Close the file
        load.close();
    }

    //If everything loaded fine
    return true;
}
```

Here is 'Dot.h' which is in the same directory as all the other files:

```
#ifndef DOT_H_INCLUDED
#define DOT_H_INCLUDED

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include "vars.h"
#include "prototypes.h"

//The dot
class Dot{
    private:
    //The X and Y offsets of the dot
    int x, y;

    //The velocity of the dot
    int xVel, yVel;

    //Game variables
    int chakra, maxChakra;

    public:
    //Initializes the variables
    Dot();

    //Takes key presses and adjusts the dot's velocity
    void handle_input();

    //Moves the dot
    void move();

    //Shows the dot on the screen
    void show();

    //Set the dot's x/y offsets
    void set_x( int X );
    void set_y( int Y );

    //Get the dot's x/y offsets
    int get_x();
    int get_y();

    //Chakra
    int getChakra();
    int getMaxChakra();
    void setChakra(int amount);
    void useChakra(int amount);
    void gainChakra(int amount);
};

Dot::Dot()
{
    //Initialize the offsets
    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    //Initialize the velocity
    xVel = 0;
    yVel = 0;

    //Initialize chakra
    maxChakra = 300;
    chakra = maxChakra;
}

void Dot::set_x( int X )
{
    x = X;
}

void Dot::set_y( int Y )
{
    y = Y;
}

int Dot::get_x()
{
    return x;
}

int Dot::get_y()
{
    return y;
}

int Dot::getChakra(){
    return chakra;
}

int Dot::getMaxChakra(){
    return maxChakra;
}

void Dot::setChakra(int amount){
    chakra = amount;
    //if (chakra<0) bg = SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 );
}

void Dot::useChakra(int amount){
    chakra -= amount;
    //if (chakra<0) bg = SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 );
}

void Dot::gainChakra(int amount){
    chakra += amount;
    if (chakra>maxChakra) chakra = maxChakra;
}

void Dot::handle_input()
{
    //If a key was pressed
    if( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        //Adjust the velocity
        switch( event.key.keysym.sym )
        {
            case SDLK_UP:
            yVel -= DOT_HEIGHT / 2;
            if(!jutsuActive) DOT_DIRECTION = 0;
            break;

            case SDLK_DOWN:
            yVel += DOT_HEIGHT / 2;
            if(!jutsuActive) DOT_DIRECTION = 2;
            break;

            case SDLK_LEFT:
            xVel -= DOT_WIDTH / 2;
            if(!jutsuActive) DOT_DIRECTION = 3;
            break;

            case SDLK_RIGHT:
            xVel += DOT_WIDTH / 2;
            if(!jutsuActive) DOT_DIRECTION = 1;
            break;
            default: ;
        }
    }
    //If a key was released
    else if( event.type == SDL_KEYUP )
    {
        //Adjust the velocity
        switch( event.key.keysym.sym )
        {
            case SDLK_UP: yVel += DOT_HEIGHT / 2; break;
            case SDLK_DOWN: yVel -= DOT_HEIGHT / 2; break;
            case SDLK_LEFT: xVel += DOT_WIDTH / 2; break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT: xVel -= DOT_WIDTH / 2; break;
            default: ;
        }
    }
}

void Dot::move()
{
    //Move the dot left or right
    x += xVel;

    //If the dot went too far to the left or right
    if( ( x < 0 ) || ( x + DOT_WIDTH > SCREEN_WIDTH ) || jutsuActive )
    {
        //Move back
        x -= xVel;
    }

    //Move the dot up or down
    y += yVel;

    //If the dot went too far up or down
    if( ( y < 0 ) || ( y + DOT_HEIGHT > SCREEN_HEIGHT ) || jutsuActive )
    {
        //Move back
        y -= yVel;
    }
}

void Dot::show()
{
    //Show the dot
    //apply_surface( x, y, dot, screen, &clipsChar[DOT_DIRECTION] );
}

#endif // DOT_H_INCLUDED
```

If you can help me fix this that would be amazing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have a recursive include.  prototypes.h is including Dot.h, and Dot.h is including prototypes.h.

Because the guards are preventing a true recursion, you just get an unexpected include order.

Because prototypes.h doesn't actually need the definition of class Dot, you could just forward declare Dot instead:

```
#ifndef PROTOTYPES_H_INCLUDED
#define PROTOTYPES_H_INCLUDED

//The headers
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include "vars.h"

using namespace std;
class Dot;

bool load_files( Dot &thisDot, Uint32 &bg );

#endif // PROTOTYPES_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Vaughn's solution of forward declaring Dot is much better than including the .h file. In big systems the compilation time can be dominated by the cost of reading the .h files into each compilation unit. Getting into this habit will improve your life in the future